# How to ensure only last child can be deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app an `invoice` can have up to 3 `reminders`.

How can I make sure that only the *last* reminder of each invoice can be deleted by the user?

For example, if a user has created 2 reminders for an invoice, only the second reminder should be deletable (the one with the greater `id` to be precise).

How can this be achieved?

Thanks for any help.

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice

  def deletable?
     ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
def deletable?
  self == invoice.reminders.last
end
```

However this will not handle the situation where a reminder is added between the time where you check if the reminder is deletable, and the actual deletion.